# GVFs metadata is not supported

Tags: gvfs

I tried changing the lock screen on my newly installed ubuntu. I tried the following to modify the theme

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

When the text editor opened, it was blank and the terminal displayed this warning.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGjRR.png)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? That file is no longer present in 20.04 and newer.

Comment: Thanks. Now how do I edit in the newer version? In my case 20.04.3.

Comment: There's an [edit] link between the post and the comments.

Comment: it helped. Thanks. Loving the community!